# cordova platform add ios --save exited with exit code 1

Tags: cordova, ionic3

I first added the android platform to my app with the following command:

```
    ionic cordova platform add android
```

It worked fine, but when I tried adding the ios, I ran into following problem:

```
 cordova platform add ios --save
 Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@0.0.1
 Failed to fetch platform cordova-ios@0.0.1
 Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is 
 incorrect.
 Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
 Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
 npm ERR! code ETARGET
 npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for cordova-ios@0.0.1
 npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies 
  are requesting
 npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR!     /Users/tejashripatange/.npm/_logs/2019-03- 
   27T16_40_10_705Z-debug.log
 [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
    cordova platform add ios --save exited with exit code 1.
    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Also, it generated a log file like below:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'cordova-ios@0.0.1',
1 verbose cli   '--production',
1 verbose cli   '--save-exact' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.14.2
4 verbose npm-session 6aad67a67d24ca34
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-ios 172ms (from cache)
8 silly registry:manifest no matching version for cordova-ios@0.0.1 in the cache. Forcing revalidation
9 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-ios 54ms (from cache)
10 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for cordova-ios@0.0.1 No matching version found for cordova-ios@0.0.1
11 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
12 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 1144ms
13 verbose type version
14 verbose stack cordova-ios: No matching version found for cordova-ios@0.0.1
14 verbose stack     at pickManifest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-pick-manifest/index.js:65:11)
14 verbose stack     at fetchPackument.then.packument (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/registry/manifest.js:52:18)
14 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
14 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
14 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
14 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
14 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
14 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
14 verbose stack     at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
15 verbose cwd /Users/tejashripatange/Downloads/KGKLive
16 verbose Darwin 18.2.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "cordova-ios@0.0.1" "--production" "--save-exact"
18 verbose node v10.14.2
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ETARGET
21 error notarget No matching version found for cordova-ios@0.0.1
22 error notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
22 error notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
23 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

It actually used to work don't know why is it not generating the platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, it looks like Cordova tries to install `cordova-ios@0.0.1`, which doesn't exist. You should check if you have a reference to that somewhere.

Try to instead set the version explicitly:

```
cordova platform add ios@5.0.0 --save
```